# Is it possible to create an Android app that utilizes a Google Latitude API?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-latitude

Is it possible to create an Android app that utilizes a Google Latitude API?  I'm assuming you'd probably need a Google Map Key and fingerprint such as you need to access Google Maps through an Android app.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use 
[google-api-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android).